# i3wm некорректно отображает Qt5 приложения

Tags: linux, qt5, i3wm

i3wm (а точнее i3wm-gaps) некорректно отображает Qt5 приложения, а именно делает виджеты нисоразмерно большими. Пытался что то изменить через qt5ct, но он закрывается при нажатие на "таблица стилей"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось "сбросить тему". Для этого я удалил из переменных среды всё что связанно с Qt. После перезагрузки стало отображаться нормально.